# How to subset specific values from whole data.frame without defining every column?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

My data.frame (df) consists of 20 different columns. 
All my columns are integer values (range 0 - 99)

Let's say I would like to subset my data of col1 and col2 that have lower values(x) than 4. 
So my code could be:

```
df2 <- subset(df, col1 < 4 & col2 < 4)
```

That's fine.

But how can I modify my code to get a new subset of all my 20 columns. without specifying every particular column. ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick correct -> I'm looking for an efficient way to code cases like that from my example

Comment: @G5W when the data have `NA` will create the problem ~

Comment: @MrFlick  You are right.  I was mis-reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a faster method than `apply` using `max.col`, matrix subsetting, and logical subsetting.
First, construct a sample dataset.

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(1:3, 5, replace=TRUE),
                  b=sample(1:4, 5, replace=TRUE),
                  c=sample(1:6, 5, replace=TRUE))
```

It looks like this.

```
dat
  a b c
1 1 3 5
2 2 1 4
3 2 1 2
4 2 3 6
5 3 3 2
```

Notice that only the third column has values greater than 4 and that only 2 such elements in the column pass the test. Now, we do

```
dat[dat[cbind(seq_along(dat[[1]]), max.col(dat))] > 4, ]
  a b c
1 1 3 5
4 2 3 6
```

Here, `max.col(dat)` returns the column with the maximum value for each row. `seq_along(dat[[1]])` runs through the row numbers. `cbind` returns a matrix that we use to pull out the maximum value for each row using matrix subsetting. Then, compare these values to see if any are greater than 4 with `> 4`, which returns a logical vector whose length is the number of rows of the data.frame. This is used to subset the data.frame by row.

Comment: great alternative! thank you very much for your answer and help! :)

Comment: @dvantwisk I upvoted your answer because it looks cleaner, but `apply` is notoriously slow, especially for data.frames. It is essentially a fancy wrapper for a `for` loop that has to convert the data.frame to a matrix prior to running that loop. `max.col`, while still requiring matrix conversion, is optimized under the hood, and matrix indexing (subsetting) is usually incredibly fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
df2 <- df[apply(df, 1, max) < 4,]
```